# I expect that i will have image via matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm newbee in python and mostly do this because of the coursera lectures.
This lectures have Jupyter notebook, where you can look at executing python code on webplatform how i get it.

[Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx0xo.png)

So i decided to compile this program (install python, pip, matplotlib and so far and so forth) on my PC and use this as some sort of python 101.

Now my code is compiling but i dont have any image output (idk maybe it shouldnt, lol)

my sample code i started with:

```
  1 from __future__ import print_function  
  2 import matplotlib                                                                                                   
  3 matplotlib.use('Agg')
  4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  5 import numpy as np
  6 import math
  7
  8 print("hello world!")
  9 SIZE=4
 10 img = np.zeros((SIZE,SIZE))
 11 for n in range (0, SIZE):
 12     for m in range (0,SIZE):
 13         if (n & 0x1) ^ (m & 0x1):
 14             img[n, m] = 255
 15
 16 plt.matshow(img);
```

so after: $ python file_name.py i just have Hello World outputted. (WSL on widnows using)

What i got to do to show my plot?

[gif with my sequencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1jHA.gif)

Comment: Add `plt.show()` at the end?

Comment: @DavidG, thx for the prompt answer i tried it, and it do nothing.

Comment: and now I'm think that `plt.matshow(img)` should do the same as just `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `matplotlib.use('Agg')` is especially asking not to render any output.

In a jupyter notebook, replace this line by

```
%matplotlib inline
```

to get a png image printed as output or

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

to get an interactive figure. Whether you need to use `plt.show()` at the end will depend on the case, in cases where you create the figure explicitely in the cell, it is not needed.

Outside of a jupyter notebook, e.g. using a usual python script. You would need to simply remove the line `matplotlib.use('Agg')` or replace it by some interactive backend, e.g.

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

or

```
matplotlib.use('QtAgg')
```

In those cases, you specifically need to call `plt.show()` to invoke the interactive plotting window.

Comment: I do not use Jupyter notebook now it's just me and python compiler as i understand it.

Comment: That wasn't clear from the question, but the argument is similar. I updated the answer to cover both cases.

Comment: Should i install jupyter notebook and IPython or there is some workaround and i can do my "homework" with just common python compiler and text editor?

Comment: No need to install Jupyter. I just gave that answer, because the question read as if you were already using it. Refer to the second part of the answer if you want to run scripts. (Btw. python is interpreted, not compiled.)

Comment: I tried it and i get error `_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`

Comment: Are you sure you run this on your PC and not on some server?

Comment: i add a gif with my sequencing in my post

Comment: I see. You are running this on Window Subsystem for Linux, this is essentially a server, which does not have any graphical output. *"To use WSL with graphical programs, an X server will need to be installed on the Windows 10 system and the DISPLAY variable will need to be set in Bash. Fortunately, there are many X servers that run on Windows; some of the more popular free ones are Xming, Cygwin X, and vcXsrv."* I guess getting this to work is too broad for a question here.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help and patience, really appreciate it!

Comment: Xming server with default settings do the trick for me right out of the box